# Setting width of a web form using Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a default web project using `Visual Studio 2013`. I am able to run the default project created. I am trying to adjust the `width` of the `form` and increase it from its default size.

I have added a new page and placed a `div` as follows

```
<div class=container-fluid">
<div>
```

I have created a custom style sheet and added to the page. The content of the style sheet is as follows

```
.container-fluid {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1600px; 
}
```

if I change decrease `max-width` to `400`, the screen is shown small. If increase it to higher values it doesnt move beyond the width shown in the attached picture. I am using `Bootstrap 2.2.0`

[image]

Comment: but what is the problem you are facing..?

Comment: use min-width instead of max-width

Comment: I want the contents to occupy the whole page - from corner to the other corner with a minimal border. But I could not extend it beyond the table shown in the above image.

Comment: ind bootstrap 3  container-fluid default value occupy the whole page .. try don't redefine ..

Comment: It's working. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap will help you one this.

There are two container classes to choose from:

1. The `.container` class provides a responsive fixed width container
2. The `.container-fluid` class provides a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport

> Note: Containers are not nestable (you cannot put a container inside
>   another container).

The following example shows the code for a basic Bootstrap page (with a full width container):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>My First Bootstrap Page</h1>
  <p>This part is inside a .container-fluid class.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```